# How to run vbscript code at certain browser width

Tags: javascript, cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm turning a clients website into a responsive site and they have lots of vbscript in the content of their home page. At mobile widths they've stripped out a lot of content which means there's lots of code that's being executed but not displayed thanks to `display:none`

Is there a way to run vbscript code when you hit a minimum width of 768px?

I thought about using javascript to get the screen width and store it as a cookie and use vbscript to get the cookie to obtain the screen width:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript"> 
var width = screen.width; 
document.cookie = 'YourDomain=ScreenWidthB='+width; 
</SCRIPT> 
<%Dim ScreenWidth%> 
<%ScreenWidth=request.cookies("YourDomain")("ScreenWidthB")%>
```

but I feel there may be a better solution out there. Also the code above gives me the width of my monitor I believe, not the width of the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something you would do with any server side language.

You can either use [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for this, which has a built-in grid system to handle responsive sizing.

or you can simply use CSS to define your styles for elements with-in a certain viewport size, using the [`CSS @media`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) tag:

Your CSS would look like this example:

```
div {width:100px;}

@media (min-width:768px) {
   div { width: 50px; }
}
```

What this does is makes all div's at 100px width, but when the browser is `768px` or larger it changes the div sizing to `50px`, as defined with-in the `@media` tag.

Therefore, you can use VBScript to generate the CSS script in the page, without having to write any javascript code.  But Bootstrap may be your best bet to help build a responsive design easily/seamlessly. You may want to check it out.

---

EDIT: `Since OP has clarified not to even load the content`

You can make a cookie in javascript, and read it in your VBScript to check the viewport.

You can use [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com) for this:

```
  $(window).resize(function(e){
     var w = $(this).width();
     if(w>768) document.cookie = "viewport=768;";
     else document.cookie = "viewport=;";
  });
```

This will bind an event listener on any time the user resizes the window, to check it's size, and if above 768px, it will write the cookie or empty if not.
Then check for the viewport cookie using `Request.Cookies("viewport")`

Or better yet since you're concerned about performance, you can use Ajax to build your page when a certain viewport size is hit.

Again, you can use [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com) for this and bind to the window resize event.

```
  contentloaded = false;
  $(window).resize(function(e){
     var w = $(this).width();
     if(w>768 && !contentloaded) {
        $.get(url,function(data){
           $("div").html(data);
           contentloaded = true;
        });
     }
  });
```

I would use ajax to do this, since I'd want to show the content without the user having to refresh the screen as you would have to by using the cookie solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I don't think I was clear with my question! I already have CSS media tags in use.. example of mine. I have a latest news section. in desktop I have a News button and the following is vbscript which displays all the news. In mobile I have used media to hide the contents of the news and only display the news button. So far I have used CSS to hide the news contents. The code is still being executed which takes up unnecessary load time is that makes sense. Apologies for that!

Comment: If i had it my way it would be done with bootstrap but the $ and time constraint only allows us to turn their existing site responsive unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm after! Is there a way to update the cookie on page refresh? Because at the moment I have to refresh the page twice to get an updated cookie value. example on page visit, cookie displays value 1500px, I resize and refresh and cookie is still 1500px, I refresh once more and then it updates to 900px. Do you know what causes this? I have so far as test:
<script>
var width = $(window).width();
document.cookie = 'ScreenWidth='+width; 
</script>
<%
Dim ScreenWidth
ScreenWidth=request.Cookies("ScreenWidth")
response.Write("screen width: "&ScreenWidth)
%>

Comment: Apologies for crappy formatting in comment above. Don't know how to do code snippet in comments

Comment: Because you're only getting the size on load, and not every time the user resizes their screen.  As I said, you need to bind a listener to the window resize event, see more here: http://api.jquery.com/resize/